# replicate amazon ec2 and recreate it on local ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to move a server from ec2 -> local ubuntu.

I wonder if there's a way to copy the configuration I've done to the ec2.

supervisor, redis, rabbitmq, elasticsearch, nginx, uwsgi, thumbor to name a few..

Answer (score 0):

There is no real good way to get all of your configuration changes off of a box if you made them manually. However you could create an AMI of your instance, and export the AMI to run it on Xen locally.
According to the docks, VM Import/Export is compatible with Citrix Xen, Microsoft Hyper-V, or VMware vSphere virtualization environments
https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vm-import/
As an added benefit, it doubles as a backup.

Hope this helps